# My prefix is salty and smarts, my infix will occupy without a g,

Tags: riddle, knowledge, history

IMHO this is the hardest riley riddle I've seen.

> My prefix is salty and smarts
>   My infix will occupy without a g
>   My suffix three white triangles upon the blue
>   For I myself require a council

(you're welcome for the tag hint)

Comment: If it's of any use to someone, the three white triangles upon the blue made me think of [International maritime signal flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags), though I failed to get anything relevant out of it. :)

Comment: @Jenayah I'll go ahead and tell you its not, but good idea.

Comment: guessed that upon seeing the accepted answer, yeah ;) anyway, nice riddle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the infix but I think it is

> Witenagemot

because salty and smart:

> wit and Na (sodium)

the white triangles on blue:

> UK ministry of transportation (MOT) logo

and the whole word/council:

> " "Anglo-Saxon parliament," Old English witena gemot, from witena, genitive plural of wita "man of knowledge," related to wit (n.)) + gemot "assembly, council" " (Douglas Harper's Etymology Dictionary)

Comment: You got the Na part wrong, I was actually meaning: salt in latin is sal, sal in latin also means wit. Also, as to the infix I forgot a portion of the clue.